# How to prevent after submitting a form to revert back to the previous Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several tabs and each time I select a tab, the form is submitted sending a variable a different value (hidden from the user).  If I go say from TAB1 to TAB2, variable99 will get a value of 2, TAB3 a value of 3 and so on....  Problem I am having is that when I select TAB2, I don't want the page to revert back to TAB1.  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Submit a Form on Tab Click</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
$("#Main").tabs();
$('[id^=ui-id-]').click(function(){
var tabId = $(this).attr('id');
var tabNum = tabId.split('-')[2];
$('#form-' + tabNum).submit();
});
});
</script>


</head>

<body>



<div id="Main">
<ul>
<li><a href="#Tab1">Tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="#Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
<li><a href="#Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
<li><a href="#Tab4">Tab4</a></li>
<li><a href="#Tab5">Tab5</a></li>
<li><a href="#Tab6">Tab6</a></li>
</ul>

<form id="form-1" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="1">
</form>   

<form id="form-2" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="2">
</form> 

<form id="form-3" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="3">
</form>

<form id="form-4" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="4">
</form>

<form id="form-5" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="5">
</form>

<form id="form-6" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="6">
</form>

<div id="Tab1">
<p>Tab1</p> 
</div>
<div id="Tab2">
<p>Tab2</p>
</div>
<div id="Tab3">
<p>Tab3</p>
</div>
<div id="Tab4">
<p>Tab4</p>
</div>
<div id="Tab5">
<p>Tab5</p>
</div>
<div id="Tab6">
<p>Tab6</p>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is my code now, I removed some things, that didn't make since:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Submit a Form on Tab Click</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
</style>

<script>
$(function() {//Open function
$("#Main").tabs();
$('[id^=ui-id-]').click(function(){ //Open [id^=ui-id-]

       if (tabId == 'ui-id-1')
     {
        doAjax('1');
        }
    else if (tabId == 'ui-id-2') 
     {
      doAjax('2');
     }
    else if (tabId == 'ui-id-3') 
     {
      doAjax('3');
     }
function doAjaxSubmit(formID) { //Open doAjaxSubmin
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Tab_Click_v00.html",
    data: "Nb_var99=" + formID,
})
} //Close doAjaxSubmin
}); //Close [id^=ui-id-]
});//Close function
</script>


</head>

<body>



<div id="Main">
<ul>
<li><a href="#Tab1">Tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="#Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
<li><a href="#Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
<li><a href="#Tab4">Tab4</a></li>
<li><a href="#Tab5">Tab5</a></li>
<li><a href="#Tab6">Tab6</a></li>
</ul>



 <div id="Tab1">
 <p>Tab1</p> 
 </div>
 <div id="Tab2">
 <p>Tab2</p>
 </div>
 <div id="Tab3">
 <p>Tab3</p>
 </div>
 <div id="Tab4">
 <p>Tab4</p>
 </div>
 <div id="Tab5">
 <p>Tab5</p>
 </div>
 <div id="Tab6">
 <p>Tab6</p>
 </div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is not working. It also killed the css style?? I'll keep on trying.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question and telling us a bit about what happens to the Nb_var99 data when it reaches `Tab_Click_v00.html`?  Is there something for the user to do there (that is, does the user even need to see that page?), or what happens to the data (Nb_var99==3, Nb_var99==4, etc) once it reaches that HTML file? Also, does your server do PHP or ASP.NET or ? (in case we need to add a bit of server-side code to finish the answer?)

Comment: Also, after POSTING the Nb_var99 value over to `Tab_Click_v00.html`, do you want to update the current page at all - perhaps with a success message, or by displaying data sent back by the Tab_Click page (for this we would need to know the PHP/ASP.NET question... It's super simple to do, we just have to know.)

Comment: Hi gibberish, Nb_var99 is a variable contained in an embedded webserver (this webserver doesn't do or at least I am not aware of that it runs PHP or ASP.NET). As far as I know, it runs a software called PINK (developed by Netburner). Unfortunately, the way to load a value to its variables is to perform a post on a form. Their is no need to alert the user of this action, another embedded unit will collect this information as reference to know where the user is currently at.

Comment: Thanks for this insight - really helps. In this case, I believe that AJAX is the way to go. No need for the `.done()` function (or, in the old style AJAX, no need for a `success:` function). Just use AJAX to post the data, and you should be golden.

Comment: If I use form post and the url is: http://Tab_Click_v00.html#tab1  and I do the following:  <form id="form-1" action="Tab_Click_v00.html#tab1" method="post"> then it should work?

Comment: Not sure; try it. Honestly, though, I would use ajax. See my other response/comment below -- recently updated with further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer also uses AJAX. I will post another example, addressing your request for more information regarding the hidden iframe idea.

Notice that as you click from Tab to Tab, the user remains on the tab.

Just copy/paste into two files:

**index.php** (or whatever you wish to name it), and
**myphpprocessor.php** (if change name of this file, must also change its name in AJAX code block)

**index.php** (or mytest.html, or whatever)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

    <style>
        #msg{width:30%;height:80px;padding:10px;margin-top:20px;background-color:wheat;}
        .hidden{display:none;}
    </style>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            
                $( "#Main" ).tabs();

                $('[id^=ui-id-]').click(function() {
                    var tabId = $(this).attr('id');

                    if (tabId == 'ui-id-1') {
                        doAjax('1');
                    }else if (tabId == 'ui-id-2') {
                        doAjax('2');
                    }else if (tabId == 'ui-id-3') {
                        doAjax('3');
                    }else if (tabId == 'ui-id-4') {
                        doAjax('4');
                    }else if (tabId == 'ui-id-5') {
                        doAjax('5');
                    }

                }); //END ui-id-#.click fn
            }); //END document.ready

            function doAjax(formID) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "myphpprocessor.php",
                    data: "Nb_var99=" + formID,
                })
                .done(function( recd_from_PHP ) {
                    //No need to put ANYTHING in here, but for eg, you can do:
                    //alert('In done fn...');

                    //AS AN EXAMPLE ONLY, display message sent from server side
                    //alert("PHP side said: " + recd_from_PHP);
                    $('#msg').html('<h2>Here is what the PHP side sent:</h2>' + recd_from_PHP);

                    //AS AN EXAMPLE ONLY, click the third tab...
                    //$('[id^=ui-id-3]').click(); //Warning, this will cause endless loop -- but just demonstrating
                });

            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="Main">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Tab1">Tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Tab4">Tab4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Tab5">Tab5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Tab6">Tab6</a></li>
        </ul>

        <form id="form-1" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="1">
        </form>   

        <form id="form-2" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="2">
        </form> 

        <form id="form-3" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="3">
        </form>

        <form id="form-4" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="4">
        </form>

        <form id="form-5" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="5">
        </form>

        <form id="form-6" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="6">
        </form>

        <div id="Tab1">
            <p>Tab1</p> 
        </div>
        <div id="Tab2">
            <p>Tab2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Tab3">
            <p>Tab3</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Tab4">
            <p>Tab4</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Tab5">
            <p>Tab5</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Tab6">
            <p>Tab6</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="msg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Server Side: **myphpprocessor.php** (MUST end in .php)

```
<?php

    $id = $_POST['Nb_var99'];
    
    if ($id == 4) {
        $msg = "Return of the Tab Four";
    }else{
        $msg = 'PHP side receieved: ' .$id;
    }
    
    echo $msg;
```

Answer (score 2):

For what you want to do, there is no need to use `<form>`s and `<input>`s at all.

Just based on the tab that is clicked, you can send a 1 or a 2 or a 3 over to the desired HTML page, via AJAX.

The `<form>` construction is great when you have several fields and you wish to POST their data over to another server page for processing. However, in your case, it appears that you only wish to send a value to another page, and then return.

Here is one way to do it, using AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#Main" ).tabs();

    $('[id^=ui-id-]').click(function() {

        if (tabId == 'ui-id-1') {
            doAjax('1');
        }else if (tabId == 'ui-id-2') {
            doAjax('2');
        }else if (tabId == 'ui-id-3') {
            doAjax('3');
        }

    }); //END ui-id-#.click fn
}); //END document.ready

function doAjaxSubmit(formID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myphpprocessor.php",
        data: "Nb_var99=" + formID,
    })
    .done(function( recd_from_PHP ) {
        //No need to put ANYTHING in here, but for eg, you can do:

        //AS AN EXAMPLE ONLY, display message sent from server side
        alert("PHP side said: " + recd_from_PHP);

        //AS AN EXAMPLE ONLY, click the third tab...
        $('[id^=ui-id-3]').click();
    });

}
```

---

Another way to send form data (using a `<form>` as it was intended) is to create a hidden `<iframe>` on your page, containing the `Tab_Click_v00.html` page inside it -- and then POST to that page.

Because the form's target is already on the page in an `<iframe>`, the current page should not refesh. And because the `<iframe>` is hidden, the user should not see anything unusual.

Comment: Hi Gibberish,  I am interested on information of the hidden <iframe>.  I think, its what I need in order to prevent the page from refreshing, yet keeping it hidden from the user. Can you show me an example of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Given you're using the [jQuery Tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) control, you can use the [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) and bind to the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) event (and show the appropriate tab using the [`active`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) option):

```
$(window).load(function(){
  if(window.location.hash){
    $('#main').tabs('option','active',window.location.hash.substring(1));
  }
});
```

Then redirect the user back using `somepage.html#tabindex`

Answer (score 1):

Posting to a hidden `<iframe>`

I've never done this myself, and can see its a bit tricky.  Here are some posts that discuss how to do it:

[How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe)
[Hidden iframe submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914466/displaying-success-failure-messages-from-hidden-iframe-submit)
[Remember to specify the name= attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178223/how-to-work-with-onchange-submit-form-target-to-iframe)
[Post form in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001262/post-a-form-in-an-iframe)

You will notice that this is considerably more complicated than simply doing a basic AJAX form submission, as suggested in my previous two answers.

---

I am not sure why the AJAX solution is not appealing in your situation, but I remember when AJAX and PHP were unknown commodities to me, and perhaps that is what you are struggling with.

If so, struggle no more.  Both are much simpler than you realize.

For basic, FREE, from-the-ground-up 10-min tutorials in PHP:
[phpAcademy.org](https://phpacademy.org/course/register-login)
[thenewboston.com](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11)

---

Next, here are some good posts for getting the basics of AJAX:

[A simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734395/form-inside-of-load-not-posting-correctly/13734466#13734466)

[More complicated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887098/two-post-requests-one-after-the-other-second-post-request-doesnt-get-execut/17887642#17887642)

[Populate dropdown 2 based on selection in dropdown 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

---

My recommendation is to use the AJAX solution, but I do not understand what you are trying to achieve in the end. What is the file `Tab_Click_v00.html` going to do with the data it receives?

Perhaps if you provide more information (as a comment below this post) about the desired end result on the `Tab_Click` side, I can be of more help.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to all this and a lot of this things just go right pass my knowledge. I have used Ajax to collect dynamic information from the website.  The developer/builder of the webserver maker made his/her software in this way, I have no control over that.  I would have to go in and write an entirely new software to alter how it behaves (something I really don't want to do; time consuming + learning curve). I have an embedded unit that uses that information to detect where the user is located on the website, it then performs some action.

Comment: What happens when you try posting the data as described in the AJAX examples (esp. the 2nd one). Have you contacted the vendor? Did they agree that using AJAX is/isnot the way to do this? Check with them directly, I'm sure they'll answer such a question.

Comment: This was the response from the vendor: Well, the page that will load is defined in your form. If you change the action value, then the new 
page will load to whatever your new action is pointing to.

As for submitting the form post without refreshing, you will need to look into Ajax. There is an 
example on the forum located at forum.embeddedethernet.com describes how to use Ajax. 

NetBurner Support

Comment: [This may be the AJAX example](http://forum.embeddedethernet.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=303) of which they speak. They are using straight javascript, no jQuery (you can still use jQuery, because the AJAX is done on the client side. The server side simply sees AJAX comms as a normal POST, as though from a form. jQuery is *much* easier, IMHO). [Here's another](http://forum.embeddedethernet.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1661) -- looks like you want to be talking to Tod in their forums.